# Transform python multi dimensional array 2x100 to 100x 2

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array, is there a quick way of doing this using numpy or array?

`[ ['one','two','three'] [1,2,3] ]`

Need to convert it to the following

`[ ['one',1], ['two',2], ['three',3] ]`

Numpy or array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`.

```
a = [['one','two','three'],[1,2,3]]

new_a = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(a[0],a[1])]

print(new_a)
[['one', 1], ['two', 2], ['three', 3]]
```

### Extra

According to the comments and the answers, I suddenly got curious with the performance time among the answer by @lhopital, my answer and the answer provided by @moe. So I have created a 2d list with 260 chars and 260 values.

```
%timeit [[s, n] for s, n in zip(*a)]
40.2 µs ± 2.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit [[i, j] for i, j in zip(a[0],a[1])]
27.2 µs ± 1.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

a = np.array(a)

%timeit a.T
146 ns ± 2.47 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Apparently, `np.transpose` is the fastest method to use.

Comment: Drop the `np.array` wrapper and the `int()`.  Stick with the simple list zip 'transpose'.

Comment: Just realized, too. Thanks for reminding

Comment: For your above solution, you don't need numpy right?
Though if you are already using numpy, you could simply use the builtin transpose method:
`new_a = a.T`

Answer (score 2):

```py
q = [['one', 'two', 'three'], [1,2,3]]
a = [[s, n] for s, n in zip(*q)]
# a = [['one', 1], ['two', 2], ['three', 3]]
```

Comment: As Kevin wrote, you should use `zip`. You could also use `*`in front of variable to 'unpack' it. Instead of calling `v[i], v[j]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = np.array([['one','two','three'], [1,2,3]])

aT = a.T

print(aT)
```